# VTK / ITK Dice Similarity Coefficient on Meshes

Tags: mesh, vtk, overlap, itk

I am new to **VTK** and am trying to compute the Dice Similarity Coefficient (DSC), starting from 2 meshes.
DSC can be computed as `2 Vab / (Va + Vb)`, where `Vab` is the overlapping volume among mesh A and mesh B.

To read a mesh (i.e. an organ contour exported in .vtk format using 3D Slicer, https://www.slicer.org) I use the following snippet:

```
string inputFilename1 = "organ1.vtk";

// Get all data from the file
vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader> reader1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>::New();
reader1->SetFileName(inputFilename1.c_str());
reader1->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> struct1 = reader1->GetPolyDataOutput();
```

I can compute the volume of the two meshes using `vtkMassProperties` (although I observed some differences between the ones computed with VTK and the ones computed with 3D Slicer).

To then intersect 2 meshses, I am trying to use `vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter`. The output of this filter, however, is a set of lines that marks the intersection of the input `vtkPolyData` objects, and NOT a closed surface. I therefore need to somehow generate a mesh from these lines and compute its volume.

Do you know which can be a good, accurate way to generete such a mesh and how to do it?

---

Alternatively, I tried to use **ITK** as well. I found a package that is supposed to handle this problem (http://www.insight-journal.org/browse/publication/762, dated 2010) but I am not able to compile it against the latest version of ITK. It says that ITK must be compiled with the (now deprecated) `ITK_USE_REVIEW` flag `ON`. Needless to say, I compiled it with the new `Module_ITKReview` set to `ON` and also with backward compatibility but had no luck.

---

Finally, if you have any other alternative (scriptable) software/library to solve this problem, please let me know. I need to perform these computation automatically.

Comment: Dice overlap is usually used with images. If you want to compare two meshes, why not just use distance metric, e.g. using `vtkDistancePolyDataFilter`?

Comment: @mirni To my knowledge, the Dice Similarity Coefficient is commonly used in medical imaging literature. In particular, it is used by several radiotherapy-related papers on which I base my research.
I will also consider other metrics: thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter`

http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter.html

```
filter->SetOperationToIntersection();
```

if your data is smooth and well-behaved, this filter works pretty good. However, sharp structures, e.g. the ones originating from binary image marching cubes algorithm can make a problem for it. That said, `vtkPolyDataToImageStencil` doesn't necessarily perform any better on this regard.

I had once impression that the boolean operation on polygons is not really ideal for "organs" of size 100k polygons and more. Depends.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute a Dice Similarity Coefficient, I suggest you first generate volumes (rasterize) from the meshes by use of [vtkPolyDataToImageStencil](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/PolyDataToImageData).
Then it's easy to compute the DSC.

Good luck :)

Comment: Hi Simon, can you please elaborate your answer? Why using `ImageStencil` is a good idea? I can already compute volumes for the starting meshes using `vtkMassProperties`.

Comment: Well, it's just because I think it is difficult to get a closed intersection between two meshes, at least with VTK, so I would go with images as it seems easier and straightforward to me. But maybe someone knows a way to do what you want with only meshes

Comment: That's exactly the reason I was suggesting that DSC might be an inappropriate metric, since your data is not volumetric. I'd use a distance metric, e.g. mean distance of one surface points' to the other surface. There is `vtkDistancePolyDataFilter` that will do this for you and you would not introduce errors due to stenciling your meshes into volumes.

Comment: @MarcoVirgolin vtkMassProperties would compute the volume (as in XX mm3), but the volume we talk about in ImageStencil is a 3D image . On the other hand, consider also Haudorff distance as a metric . see also https://www.slicer.org/slicerWiki/index.php/Documentation/4.5/Modules/ContourComparison